# Does Technomancer gain a spell caster level at level one or can you only reach level 19 as a caster with technomancy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, prestige-class

The rules say +1 on all levels but first. I was wondering if the first level just doesn't give you it or if the class itself is a caster class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Technomancer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/technomancer) is a prestige class that advances the spellcasting progression of a different class.

As such, it isn't a casting class itself.

Not every prestige class that add levels of spellcasting (getting "+1 level of spellcasting" basically counts as having one more level in the casting class of your choice for determining several spellcasting-related things) does so at each and every level. In the 3.x days of D&D, the prestige classes that had that feature at every level were called "full spellcasting" PrCs and some people argued they were the only ones worth taking.

Usually, a class has less than 100% of increased spellcasting levels if the authors deemed that the other features of the class are already powerful enough. If you play up to level 20, the character will at most cast as a level 19 wizard, or sorcerer, or bard, or whatever your arcane spellcasting class of choice is, because of that last level. This does not maen that your caster level will be 19, because there are other things that could change that value (mostly used for determining spell resistance bypass checks, dispel checks and some effects of the spell including sometimes damage dice).

Comment: Is there a different technomancer? The one you linked doesn't seem to advance spellcasting at all.

Comment: @fectin the table has a "Spells per day" column that reads (at all levels but the first) "+1 level of arcane spellcasting", which is consistent with the question.

Comment: So it does. My phone's screen width precisely cuts at the end of the "special" column.